# Xcode crash after interface building?

Tags: xcode, macos

Has anyone had problems with Xcode 4.3.3 crashing on OSX Lion (10.7.4)? I am attempting to program a GUI interface and everything was perfect until I opened it to continue working on it today. This file will end up being an expert system for medical diagnosis.

A zip file is located here (http://www.mediafire.com/?14slv9xhb45214t) with all of the program files. Haven't gotten very far besides designing the interface.

I included the crash report below as well.

---

```
Process:         Xcode [9714]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.3.3 (1178)
Build Info:      IDEApplication-1178000000000000~3
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 8553856
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [273]

Date/Time:       2012-07-05 20:13:12.925 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.4 (11E53)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          197037 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           12
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  8746 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   10
Anonymous UUID:                      7C84D886-82A8-4652-B690-46D441C4DABB

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4E3002
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDESourceEditor/IDESourceEditor-1175/Classes/IDESourceCodeAdjustNodeTypesRequest.m:412
Details:  symLoc should be an instance inheriting from DVTTextDocumentLocation, but it is <IBDocumentMemberLocation: 0x401dc9a40>
Object:   <IDESourceCodeAdjustNodeTypesRequest: 0x401f137e0>
Method:   -_processFoundSymbolResults:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40010a220>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010556eb9f -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x0000000104a1f5d5 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010a625908 -[IDESourceCodeAdjustNodeTypesRequest _processFoundSymbolResults:] (in IDESourceEditor)
  3  0x0000000104a3ffc7 __DVTAsyncPerformBlock_block_invoke_0 (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff826cadfc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
  5  0x00007fff82682f02 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
  6  0x00007fff826aab35 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
  7  0x00007fff826aa486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
  8  0x00007fff8727b4d3 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
  9  0x00007fff87282781 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 10  0x00007fff8728260e BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
 11  0x0000000105b64e31 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 12  0x0000000105b64735 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 13  0x0000000105b61071 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 14  0x0000000105ddd244 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 15  0x000000010499beec (in Xcode)
 16  0x0000000000000002

objc[9714]: garbage collection is ON
abort() called
```

Comment: Xcode itself is crashing. Stack Overflow is not the right forum for that, because we can't possibly diagnose Xcode itself.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode crashes can be caused by a corrupt project file. This has happened to me a couple of times.

Xcode seems intolerant of any errors, and won't even let you get to version control.
If you are using version control you could try repairing this at the command line.

You might want to recreate your project. You should be able to copy your source files and .XIB into a new project.

Comment: I had it with Xcode 11.2.1 creating a new project and copying over files resolved the issue